# Spring/Jackson AutoMapping for field that can be multiple types

Tags: spring, jackson, resttemplate

In my application, I am trying to get an OAuth token from multiple different providers.

According to the OAuth Spec, scopes should be sent as a string that contains a space delimited list of scopes.

However, I have noticed that some implementations return the scope as a List of strings.

In my application, I would like to store the scopes as a string that contains a space delimited list of scopes, as per the specification.

To do so, I created an Dto that looks as such (this dto is the same as the entity):

```
public class OAuthTokenDto {

    // variables named to reflect OAuth Spec sends them to us

    private String access_token;

    private String refresh_token;

    private Integer expires_in;

    private String scope;

    private String token_type;

    public OAuthTokenDto() {

    }
...
}
```

Is there a way to handle the fact that scopes might be sent as a List? In its current state, I am using rest template to do the mapping and it throws an exception because of this mismatch

Comment: any sample string you receive which you are reffering to? both string and list,  would help to decide in  may be better ways

Comment: @user404 an example might be [“read”, “write”] from one source and “read write” from another. it should be stored as the second as per the oauth spec

Comment: may be different pojos  if it is possible to identify the endpoint from which you are going to issue token... I know this is not good idea but ...

Comment: @yasgur99, Is making use of JsonAnySetter and JsonAnyGetter an option?

Comment: like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56210238/how-to-parse-field-that-may-be-a-string-and-may-be-an-array-with-jackson/56210350#56210350 @yasgur99

Comment: I would really appreciate to know why the approved answer has been changed to a different one. Care to explain why that solved your issue easier?

Comment: @Coder, thought i could mark both as ansers, my bad. fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `Jackson`'s `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter`. What you can do is, you can catch the unspecified tokens with this in which case your `scope` element and then typecast depending on the object type.

```
public class OAuthTokenDto {

    // variables named to reflect OAuth Spec sends them to us

    private String access_token;

    private String refresh_token;

    private Integer expires_in;

    private String token_type;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> properties = new HaspMap<String, Object>();

    public OAuthTokenDto() {

    }

     @JsonAnyGetter
     public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
         return this.properties;
     }

     @JsonAnySetter
     public void setProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.properties.put(name, value);
     }    
}
```

And you can verify if your `scope` is an object or list of objects as follows

```java
if(properites.get("scope") instanceof List<String>)
{
    List<String> scopeList = properties.get("scope");
}
else
{
    String scope = properties.get("scope");
}
```

Thanks to @Deadpool, the following implementation works

From jackson 2.6 you can use [JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.9)

```
@JsonProperty("scope")
@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
private String[] scope;
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean solution:

Create converter class:

```
class ScopeConverter extends StdConverter<List<String>, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(List<String> scopes) {
        return scopes.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }
}
```

Use it for scope property:

```
@JsonDeserialize(converter = ScopeConverter.class)
public String scope;
```

Enable:

```
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
```

Now you can deserialize both cases scope being List and one element (with space separated scopes)